# Is this a case of overfitting? Unstable verification loss and not decreasing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, unet-neural-network

To summarize my model is 2d Unet , loss function is Dice

with epoch 350 and each one takes up to 3 min and batch size =10

Can someone please help with identifying the problem ; i cant post the loss plot but it is zig-zag and validation loss range (0.61-0.70)
the training details :
Input = (12000,144,160,4) and 9000 for training 3000 for validation.

```py
k=keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.01)

inputs = Input((144,160,4))
n_classes=4
c1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer=k, padding='same') (inputs)
c1 = Dropout(0.1) (c1)
c1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer=k, padding='same') (c1)
p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c1)

c2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer=k, padding='same') (p1)
c2 = Dropout(0.1) (c2)
c2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer=k, padding='same') (c2)
p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c2)

c3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer=k, padding='same') (p2)
c3 = Dropout(0.2) (c3)
c3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer=k, padding='same') (c3)
p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c3)

c4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer=k, padding='same') (p3)
c4 = Dropout(0.2) (c4)
c4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer=k, padding='same') (c4)
p4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)) (c4)

c5 = Conv2D(1024, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer=k, padding='same') (p4)
c5 = Dropout(0.3) (c5)
c5 = Conv2D(1024, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer=k, padding='same') (c5)

u6 = Conv2DTranspose(512, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c5)
u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
c6 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer=k, padding='same') (u6)
c6 = Dropout(0.2) (c6)
c6 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer=k, padding='same') (c6)

u7 = Conv2DTranspose(256, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c6)
u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
c7 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer=k, padding='same') (u7)
c7 = Dropout(0.2) (c7)
c7 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer=k, padding='same') (c7)

u8 = Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c7)
u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
c8 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer=k, padding='same') (u8)
c8 = Dropout(0.1) (c8)
c8 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer=k, padding='same') (c8)

u9 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c8)
u9 = concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
c9 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer=k, padding='same') (u9)
c9 = Dropout(0.1) (c9)
c9 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer=k, padding='same') (c9)

outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)



model = Model(inputs=[inputs],outputs=[outputs])
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-04), loss=dice_coefficient_loss, metrics=[dice_coefficient])
```

Any help/ advice about the model or explanation is appreciated.

Comment: It could be that the model has no clue of what to do, and just produces some "average" value all the time. This could be due to an improper loss function, a network that is too small, or a learning rate that is too aggressive. See if you can make the model severely overfit first, and then step-wise try to reduce the overfitting.

Comment: thanks , how would i make it severly overfit ? i'll try that and report back

Comment: Re-use the same training batch over and over (don't generate any new batches), set dropout to zero, don't do any form of normalisation (batch or layer). Then re-add these various features one by one and tweak the hyperparameters. If the model is not able to overfit in the first place, then there is something seriously wrong (wrong labels, latent space too small, etc.)

Comment: Four things: 1) Check your train data again 2) Consider glorot_uniform_initializer that scales the initialized weight with respect to the number of inputs. 3) Check your implementation of dice_coefficient_loss 4) Consider another loss function like 1-jaccard since dice_coefficient only represents a semi-metric

Comment: Thank you for your input ; i have checked other loss functions, train data , I will look into glorot_uniform_initializer.